# Add user to WMI Control and edit configs via SDDL / powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

I am trying to create a script adding a user to root and all subnamespaces and giving him permission for 
`Execute Methods, Enable Account, Remote Enable and Read Security`
via script as you would do it in wmimgmt manually.
I tried to export the wmimgmt settings with:

`$SidHelper = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper
$SdList = @($null)
$(Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root" -Class __SystemSecurity).PsBase.InvokeMethod("GetSD",$SdList)
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($SdList) | Set-Content sdlist.txt`

and importing them back with:

`$SdList = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($(Get-Content sdlist.txt))
$SidHelper = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper
$RootSecurity = $(Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root" -Class __SystemSecurity)
$RootSecurity.PsBase.InvokeMethod("SetSd",$SdList)` (as found [here](http://damn-software.blogspot.com/2017/06/scripting-wmi-namespace-security-with.html))
When doing this the right permissions are given but instead of the SID of the user I want to add it says unknown user.
1. Do you guys know why the script is not running as desired?
2. Do you have any idea how to add an user and give him permissions in wmimgmt via script besides the script mentioned above?

Thanks and cheers,
Uno

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the base type changes.
** BEFORE EXPORT **

```
$sdlist.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

** After Deseralization **

```
$sdlist2.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

** Try type casting it back with **[System.Array]** below **

```
$SdList = [System.Array] [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($(Get-Content sdlist.txt))
$SidHelper = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper
$RootSecurity = $(Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root" -Class __SystemSecurity)
$RootSecurity.PsBase.InvokeMethod("SetSd",$SdList)
```

** WORKS FOR ME - thank you : )
Just what I was looking for.